# What exactly is handling hosts.allow and hosts.deny?

Tags: linux, hosts.deny, hosts.allow

On a Linux machine, there is **hosts.allow** and **hosts.deny** to either allow or deny certain hosts to access services running on the machine.

The question is, **what exactly is taking care of allowing or refusing those connections? Is there a daemon doing this, or is it the kernel, something else?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it's called TCP Wrappers - a program is compiled to make use of the features (such as 'portmap', part of the NFS world) which then hooks into hosts.allow/deny and such.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Wrapper

https://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5.5/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-services-tcp-wrappers.html

Answer (score 4):

This is handled by a Library called [TCP Wrappers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Wrapper).
This library is a wrapper to standard Unix/Linux networking function adding ACL capabilities based on hosts.allow and hosts.denied.
It's a pretty old system.